# How to listen to a new incoming email in gmail and save it to a file

Tags: gmail

Hello I need to listen to a new incoming email in gmail and save it into a file

I understand that IFTTT does not support this

Is there another way (not using google cloud which I understand needs payment)?

thank you

Comment: I wonder if you could do something with app script.   Interesting ideas

Comment: What is app script?